# Updating map values in place

Tags: c++, stl

How could I simplify this code to update the `int` value in the `map` in place?

Basically I want to leave the `exceeds` unchanged (which is the `bool`) and just update the `int` value.

```
std::map<OrderInfo, std::pair<int, bool>> ncpOrders;

int NotCompletelyProcessedOrders::IncAttempts(OrderInfo& ordInfo) {
    auto it = ncpOrders.find(ordInfo);
    const bool firstTimeProcessing = it == ncpOrders.end();
    auto v = it->second;
    const int newAttempts = (firstTimeProcessing ? 0 : v.first) + 1;
    const bool exceeds = firstTimeProcessing ? false : v.second;
    ncpOrders[ordInfo] = std::pair(newAttempts, exceeds);
    return newAttempts;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have already figured out that `it->second` is the pair holding the data. Nothing stops you from also accessing `it->second->first`, and assign it a new value.

Comment: ah thanks, I didn't realize it was that simple

Comment: In the map `it->first` is const, to preserve the sort order, but `it->second` is writable.

Comment: should it not be `it->second.first` ? or am I misunderstanding something

Comment: Yes, it should be `it->second.first`. I was typing too fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make this over-complicated. Note that default construction of `std::pair<int, bool>` meets your requirement, so you can just do:

```cpp
std::map<OrderInfo, std::pair<int, bool>> ncpOrders;

int NotCompletelyProcessedOrders::IncAttempts(OrderInfo& ordInfo) {
    return ++ncpOrders[ordInfo].first;
}
```

and outcome should be exact the same.

https://godbolt.org/z/c1Ghsb4Ps

Comment: ah, thanks.. I did not realize that `map[]` performs an insertion if necessary

Answer (score 2):

You could use `std::map::try_emplace` to achieve this. Note that in this case since the default constructed value already matches your desired initial value, @MarekR's approach yields simpler code.

```
int NotCompletelyProcessedOrders::IncAttempts(OrderInfo& ordInfo) {
    return ++(ncpOrders.try_emplace(ordInfo, 0, false).first->second.first);
}
```

The result of `std::map::try_emplace` is a `std::pair<iterator, bool>` containing the position corresponding to the key after the operation. `->second.first` provides you with the `first` member variable of the map value.

Note: You imho should change the parameter of your function to `OrderInfo const& ordInfo`: the parameter passed is never modified and must be comparable with its const version, so adding const to makes this applicable in more scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
int NotCompletelyProcessedOrders::IncAttempts(OrderInfo& ordInfo) {
    auto it = ncpOrders.find(ordInfo);
    const bool firstTimeProcessing = it == ncpOrders.end();
    if (firstTimeProcessing) {
        ncpOrders[ordInfo] = std::pair(1, false);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        auto v = it->second;
        return ++v.first; // increment New Attempts
    }
}
```

there was a bug in the original code, I guess this is as concise as I can get it. I'm new to `C++` so hopefully I didn't make some incorrect assumptions about being able to use prefix `++`